# Importar dados do Mysql para Excel

Tags: mysql, python, microsoft-excel, python-2.7

To querendo importar dados do Mysql para o excel usando Python, quando tento faze-lo da um erro de *tuple*. Alguém com mais experiencia pode me ajudar?

Segui o código e o erro:

```
# coding=utf-8

from Tkinter import *
from os import popen
import tkMessageBox
import sys
import ttk
import os,tkFileDialog
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import MySQLdb
import PIL
import xlwt
import xlrd
import xlutils

class criarXLS:
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        self.master = master
        self.tela = Frame(width=500,height=300)
        self.tela.place(x=10,y=10)
        self.botGerar = Button(self.tela,text='Gerar Rel.',command=self.criarTabela)
        self.botGerar.grid(row=1,column=1)

    def conexaoBanco(self):
        BANCO = "ipuser_cde"
        USER = "root"
        PASSWD = "charlote1"
        HOST = "192.168.1.249"
        try:
            con = MySQLdb.connect(db=BANCO, user=USER, passwd=PASSWD, host=HOST)
            print("Conseguiu conectar ao Banco de Dados")
            #self.desativarOPDB()
        except MySQLdb as erro:
            print("Nao conseguiu conectar ao Banco de Dados.: ", erro)

        return con

    def criarTabela(self):
        self.workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
        self.worksheet = self.workbook.add_sheet('Rel.User')

        db = self.conexaoBanco()
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "select iduser,nome,email from usuario"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        dadosUser = cursor.fetchall()


        self.worksheet.write(0,0, u'ID')
        self.worksheet.write(0,1, u'Nome')
        self.worksheet.write(0,2, u'Email')
        for i,user in enumerate(dadosUser()):
            self.worksheet.write(i + 1, 0, user['iduser'])
            self.worksheet.write(i + 1, 1, user['nome'])
            self.worksheet.write(i + 1, 2, user['email'])
        self.workbook.save('Rel-User.xls')
        db.close()


root = Tk()
root.geometry('1350x700+0+0')
root.configure(background='Grey21')
criarXLS(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:/CharIp ServerFTP_1.1/CharIP_1.1.5/criar_rel.py", line 62, in criarTabela
    for i,user in enumerate(dadosUser(0)):
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: Qual é a linha do erro no seu código?

Comment: no caso linha 51

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dadosUser = cursor.fetchall()
# ...
for i,user in enumerate(dadosUser()):
    # ...
```

Você está tentando usar `dadosUser()` como uma função, `dadosUser` contém uma lista de tuplas ou uma lista vazia segundo a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html).

Para iterar sobre a lista, retire `()`:

```
for i,user in enumerate(dadosUser):
    # ...
```

Comment: fiz a alteraçao e me deu o seguinte erro:'Conseguiu conectar ao Banco de Dados
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:/CharIp ServerFTP_1.1/CharIP_1.1.5/criar_rel.py", line 52, in criarTabela
    self.worksheet.write(i + 1, 0, user['iduser'])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str'

Comment: Fiz como me passou

Comment: for i,user in enumerate(dadosUser):
            self.worksheet.write(int(i) + 1, 0, user['iduser'])
            self.worksheet.write(int(i) + 1, 1, user['nome'])
            self.worksheet.write(int(i) + 1, 2, user['email'])
        self.workbook.save('Rel-User.xls')
        db.close()

Comment: da o seguinte erro:Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:/CharIp ServerFTP_1.1/CharIP_1.1.5/criar_rel.py", line 52, in criarTabela
    self.worksheet.write(int(i) + 1, 0, user['iduser'])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str

Comment: add no skype dr.lauser@hotmail.com

Comment: @DiuniorRonaldoBrumLauser Faça essa alteração: `self.worksheet.write(i + 1, 0, user[0])`, `self.worksheet.write(i + 1, 1, user[1])`, e `self.worksheet.write(i + 1, 2, user[2])`, dessa forma você acessa `user` pelo índice.

Comment: Cara vlw pela ajuda deu super certo, passei horas quebrando a cabeça, para solucionar isso obrigado mesmo

Comment: @DiuniorRonaldoBrumLauser Disponha! se possível marque a resposta como "aceita" clicando na seta abaixo da pontuação!

Comment: desculpa a ignorancia e que sou novo nisso onde marco a resposta?